# Show that $L ⊂ \mathbb{P}^3$ can be written as $L = V (w + ay + bz, x + cy + dz)$ for some $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Suppose that the Fermat cubic surface is given by 
$X =V(w^3 +x^3 +y^3 +z^3)\subset \mathbb{P}^3.$

Show that every line $L ⊂ \mathbb{P}^3$ can be written (up to some permutation of the variables)
as
$L = V (w + ay + bz, x + cy + dz)$
for some $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$.

attempt: let $w +ay + bz = 0$ and $x + cy + dz = 0$. Then solving for $x$ and $y$, we have $ w = -ay - bz$ and $x = -cy - dz$ for some $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$. Then every line is in $X$  if and only if  $w^3 + x^3+ y^3 + z^3 = 0$ implies $(-ay - bz)^3 + (-cy - dz)^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 0$.

I know that every smooth cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ contains exactly $27$ lines.

I don't know how to continue. Can someone please help? thank you for any feedback.
This problem required third roots of $-1$.

Comment: Your question about showing that every line in $\mathbb P^3$ can be written as $V(w+ay+bz,x+cy+dz)$ appears to have nothing to do with the Fermat cubic at all. It's just a restatement of the fact in linear algebra that any $2\times 4$ matrix of maximal rank can be converted to the matrix $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 & a & b \\ 0 & 1 & c & d \end{array} \right)$ by row operations (up to a possible permutation of the columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a nice trick for finding the lines in the Fermat cubic. If $\eta = \exp(\pi i /3)$, then you can factorise the Fermat cubic like this:
$$ x^3 + y^3 + z^3+ w^3 = (x - \eta y)(x - \eta^3 y)(x - \eta^5y)+ (z - \eta w)(z - \eta^3 w)(z - \eta^5 w)$$

This immediately proves that the cubic contains the following nine lines:
$$ x - \eta^a y = z - \eta^b w= 0, \ \ \ \ \ a = 1,3,5, \ \ \  b = 1,3,5.$$

You get another eighteen lines using the same method after permuting the coordinates $x,y,z,w$.

Comment: So $\exp(\pi i/3)$ represents the primitive third roots of $-1$? And then the $9$ lines can be  1) $x + \eta y = z + \eta w = 0$  ,and  2) $x + \eta y = z + \eta^3 w = 0$, and 3) $x + \eta y = z + \eta^5 w = 0$, and 4) $x + \eta^3 y = z + \eta w = 0$, and 5) $x + \eta^3 y = z + \eta^3 w = 0$, and 6) $x + \eta^3 y = z + \eta^5 w = 0$, and 7)  $x + \eta^5 y = z + \eta w = 0$,and  8) $x + \eta^5 y = z + \eta^3 w = 0$ and 9) $x + \eta^5 y = z + \eta^5 w = 0$?

Comment: Yes. Then you get another nine by pairing $x$ with $z$ and $y$ with $w$, plus another nine by pairing $x$ with $w$ and $y$ with $z$.

Comment: It's not hard to factor $x^3+1$...

Comment: Factoring $x^3+ y^3$ is really the same.

Comment: yes $ (x^3 + y^3) = (x+y) (x^2 - xy  + y^2)= (x+y)[(x^2 + y^2) -xy]  $. But I don't see how you introduced the $\eta $ variable

Comment: The roots of $x^3 + 1  = 0$ are $x = \eta, \eta^3, \eta^5$. Therefore, $x^3 + 1 = (x - \eta)(x - \eta^3)(x - \eta^5)$.

Comment: Sorry, I missed some minus signs...

Comment: I guess you are using the fundamental theorem of algebra to show the roots in general.

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely right.

Comment: One last question, could we have defined the primitive root third roots of unit as $\eta = \exp(2 \pi i/3)$? rather than $\eta = \exp( \pi i/3)$

Comment: Yeah I think so!